# How does "imprinting a voltage" work?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

In products such as KNX there are only two wires used to communicate between a potentially large number of devices, and also provide power at the same time. For example in KNX the normal voltage on the bus is 30V, and to transmit a bit the voltage changes +/- 5V, see page 33-36 of http://knx.com.ua/attachments/article/132/KNX-basic_course_full.pdf

What I would like to understand is how such a circuit can be built. What I can see in the linked pdf is after the power supply there is a "choke" which has close to 0 ohm resistance for DC and very high resistance to AC, I understand this prevents the power-supply from overriding the data. But how is such a choke constructed?

Furthermore, I would like to understand how to construct a device that can raise/lower the voltage on the bus by 5-6V without using external power.

I do not have a background in electrical engineering, I studies computer science, and have a basic understanding of resistors, capacitors, inductors, and I would like to be able to model such a circuit, i.e., in ltspice to understand how it works (I am not searching for a working model, my goal is to understand it).

Comment: such a choke is literally just an inductor. In addition to that you would probably want a capacitor to couple the signal onto the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a capacitor acts as a open circuit for DC, and as a short circuit for (high-enough frequency) AC. Complementarily, an inductor acts as a short circuit for DC and an open circuit for (high enough frequency) AC.

So you can construct a bias tee like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxehTH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the load sees a DC current coming from `VDC` through the inductor, and added to that an AC current coming from `VAC` through the capacitor.

The circuit you described in your question works essentially the same way, but possibly a bit more elaborate (but since you haven't shared the circuit I can't say exactly how).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, especially for mentioning "bias tee", this seems to be the right keyword to learn how to dimension L1 and C1.